# Send html with some image via nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I would like to send an email via nodemailer that contains one logo in the html template of the email

```
<img src="img/logo.png" id="logo"></img>
```

I send the email with **nodemailer** but when i open it, the image there isn't. 
How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to provide the whole image adress for example

```
https://yourdomain.com/img/logo.png
```

when we are at email client we cannot access our server like we locally  do in our htmls

Note:
if port is there it should be mention aswell. It should be compelte image url which you can hit and access in browser aswell